# Does any self-intersect curve can be uniformly approximated by non-self-intersect curves?

Tags: general-topology, curves

Consider a continues curve $\Gamma^*:r(t), t\in [0,1]$, in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Suppose $\Gamma^*$ is self-intersected. Does $\Gamma^*$ can be uniformly approximated by a sequence of non-self-intersect curves  $\Gamma_n:r_n(t), t\in [0,1], n=1,2,....$?

If $d=2$, the answer is no. An example: the curve '4'.

How about $d \ge 3$? I think the answer is yes. But I am not sure, especially when $\Gamma^*$ has infinite self-intersection points and it is space filling. -- It is yes by using the polygonal curves.

---

More general cases: Consider a continues function $f^*: [0,1]^m \to \mathbb{R}^d, d>m$. Does $f^*$ can be uniformly approximated by a sequence of non-self-intersect functions $f_n:[0,1]^m \to \mathbb{R}^d, n=1,2,....$?

Comment: Notation: instead of writing $r(t), t \in [0, 1]$, in $\mathbb{R}^d$, you can write: $r: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: Yes, you can use polygonal approximation.

Comment: Any curve may be approximated by a polynomial curve.  That is at least a way to avoid infinitely many self intersections.

Comment: After polygonal approximation, you can then follow up by general position to get no intersections at all.

Comment: Thanks. The polygonal curves work.